# iOS Barcode Scanner SDK for Bluetooth Scanners

Tags: ios, barcode-scanner

I need to integrate a solution into my application that allows the user to use a handheld barcode scanner that is connected to an iPad via Bluetooth to scan data into the app.  I currently have the Motorola CS3070, but I was hoping to find a library/framework that works with multiple devices.

I've done quite a bit of looking around and have only been able to find libraries that utilize the built-in camera for barcode scanning. I have found a few third party libraries for hand held devices, but these libraries only work with specific readers.

So my question is has anyone come across of a library/framework that will allow an iOS device to accept data from a bluetooth barcode scanner such as the Motorola 3070?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Miken,
Socket Mobile (full disclosure, my employer) can supply and SDK for the Socket Mobile Bluetooth Cordless Handheld Scanners (CHS) for iOS.  We have a full set of API's that will allow you full control over our scanners.  Our SDK does only support the Socket Scanners however.

Also, when looking for a scanner to use with iOS, you should look for one that is Apple MFI approved, that allows the scanner to operate in Serial Port Profile mode, which is much more efficient than the Bluetooth HID mode.

Socket has a low end scanner that will only read 1D barcodes, on up to an imager scanner that can read almost all 2D barcodes.

Using the SDK allows you to connect to any of our cordless scanners.

Please see the Socket Mobile web site for more information http://www.socketmobile.com/support/developers

Regards,

Len

Comment: Miken, thanks for the reply. My company actually ordered us the Socket CHS 7Ci v3 model and I'm just waiting for my manager to register us with the Socket development program so I can get my hands on the SDK. I searched and searched and was not even able to find another MFI barcode scanner on the market. I'll check back in with this thread and let you all know how the development goes with the SocketScan 10 SDK. Thanks!

Comment: Miken, looking forward to hearing your feedback with integrating the SDK into an app. I, also, can't seem to find any other Mfi scanners on the market.

Comment: You all charge 20 bucks for access to your SDK? Are you crazy?  Seeks other solution right now.

Comment: I really don't get the $20 pricing either. I can obviously afford $20.... "but, why" http://reactiongifs.com/r/but-why.gif Socket Mobile has a great little product, but paying for the SDK is just silly. If someone builds a great app with it, you'll sell more barcode scanners. Win-win.